# Handling multiple request from client to update a column in table in spring application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, concurrency, spring-jdbc

I have a table called Balance in that table i have employee and the employee points.

[image]

Lets say the employee John is using mobile and web app simultaneously he places order at the same time.

So currently when he tries to place order from both the app the point should be updated accordingly.

When he tries to place order simultaneoulsy each request is getting 5000 point and based on cart value of john the point is updated.

From mobile app he redeeemed 2000 points so the updated amount is 5000-2000 ie 3000
From web app he redeemed 1000 point so the updatded amount should be 3000-1000 ie 2000

But in current scenario the updated amount is 5000-1000 = 4000.(For web app dirty read)

What should i do in order to make sure the transaction is proper.

I have added isolation level to SERIALIZABLE but in this case when second request updates the table column points

I get org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException:

What should i do in order to make sure that both the simultaneous request update the table with proper points.

Below is my code

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void updatePoints(String employee,int points){
    Object[] arr = new Object[] {points, employeeId};
    getJdbcTemplate().update("UPDATE BALANCE SET POINTS =POINTS -? WHERE EMPLOYEEID=?",arr);
}
```

PLEASE FIND UPDTAED CODE ABOVE CODE WAS ONLY FOR UNDERSTANDING PURPOSE
Used Transactional at service layer not in dao layer

```
@Override
    @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public void putFinalCartItems(String employeeCode, List<String> cartId, Map<String, Object> statusMap,int userId) {
        CartItems carPoints = repoDao.getFinalCartItems(cartId,employeeCode);//here i have used select query with join from Balance Table
        try {
        
            
            String orderNo=null;
            String mainOrderNo=OrderIdGenerator.getOrderId();
            List<CartItems> finalCartItems = repoDao.getBifurcatedFinalCart(cartId,employeeCode);//here i have used select query with join from Balance Table
            Integer balance = Integer.parseInt(finalCartItems.get(0).getPoints());
            Integer successCount=0;
            try {
                
                for(CartItems cartEntityId : finalCartItems) {
                    balance = balance-Integer.parseInt(cartEntityId.getTotalNoOfPoint());
        
                     orderNo="TRANS-"+cartEntityId.getId();
                     successCount = repoDao.placeOrder(cartEntityId);
                }
                repoDao.updatePoints(Integer.parseInt(carPoints.getTotalNoOfPoint()),userId,employeeCode);
            
            }catch(Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                successCount=0;
            }
            if(successCount>0) {
                    FinalOrder lfo = new FinalOrder();
                    lfo.setBalance(String.valueOf(totbalance));
                    lfo.setMainOrderId(mainOrderNo);
                    lfo.setTotalPointsSpent(carPoints.getTotalNoOfPoint());
                    statusMap.put("success",lfo );
                    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e ) {
            statusMap.put("error","Please try again after some time" );
        }
    }
```

Error stack trace that iam getting on second request

```
org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE BALANCE set Points=points-? where EMPLOYEEID=? ]; Transaction (Process ID 94) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 94) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:263)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
```

I want second request to be successfull simultaneoulsy with first request without dirty read.

Comment: To help you in a better way, it would be nice if you include "the rest of the code".  Alternatively, a possible solution could be move your `@Transactional` annotation to your method of your service layer, instead of your Dao one (I mean the method of the "upper layer" that invokes `updatePoints`). Probably you will need to include `propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY` too. On the other hand, how many servers do you have to manage those requests? Only one?

Comment: Trsansaction is working properly its getting rollbacked if any exception occurs.posted the actual code

Comment: your code is hard to read - can you explain on which line is the first request and on which line is the second?

Comment: Its a common method i have added in service layer iam getting two reuqest at a time causing the second request to fail with above exception

Comment: Ok I dunno how to say it nicely - it is not a nice code - it is not clear, and we can't see all the methods that are being called. So if you don't at the very LEAST explain which method is doing what good luck finding somebody to help you. Where are the "2 requests" coming from?

Comment: To "focus the problem", create a new method in your service to update only one balance and include `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)`. After that, executes the tests you mention. On the other hand, how many servers do you have to manage those requests? Only one?

Comment: Two request  coming from mobile and web application

Comment: We are using 2 differnt server locally.I mean two different JVM

Comment: We are using 2 differnt server locally.I mean two different JVM.One request to go from my local server (Web app )and other through my friend machine(mobile app)

Answer (score 2):

- `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` is bad for performance. The exception name is misleading as it is not a deadlock since you are updating the tables in same sequence assuming you  don't have some other `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` methods.
- Deadlock is when two different parallel operations try to acquire lock. Say `Txn1` involves updating `table a` first and `table b` second. `Txn2` involves updating `table b` first and `table a` second. Now if both of them run parallel, `Txn1` will lock `table a` and wants lock on `table b` , but `Txn2` has locked, `table b` first and wants  lock on `table a` first and wait for each other to give up. But that is not the case in your example. So  if you still want to proceed with `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE`, you need to catch the `DeadlockLoserDataAccessException` and retry with recalculated points at that time.
- Your real code differs from initial question. In initial question, you are incrementing the points but in real code you are replacing the points with newly calculated points. So I think if you use the approach in the initial question without `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE`, it should work.
- So the parameters you need to pass to the update points method are `pointsToReduct` not `newTotalPoints`.

```
    Object[] arr = new Object[] { pointsToReduct, employeeId };
    getJdbcTemplate().update("UPDATE BALANCE SET POINTS = POINTS - ? WHERE 
                               EMPLOYEEID = ?",arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring, with REST style requests you don't need to worry about this as Dispatcher Servlet is going to take care of simultaneous requests coming into your code one at a time.

But one solution would be to just put `@Transactional` and in the method first do select to see the current amount and then update += the amount of points. Because it is inside of a transaction there will be a row lock on database so you don't need to worry somebody else accessing it at the same time. (assuming your database provider provides such locks which most would by default)

Comment: I tried to test without using isolation but was getting unexpected result like dirty read was happening. Already using select query for checking whether the redeem point is greater than balance point within the transaction. Each request was getting points as 5000.Is there any alternative way where two request would be successfully updating the points column.